# Handling conditional SELECT and UPDATE queries from concurrent API calls

Tags: php, mysql, api, concurrency

I have a system for offering different types of prizes to users based on chance defined for them. I have a column called `totalCount` which contains the number of total prizes of that type that can be awarded, and a column called `awardedCount` which contains the number of prizes already awarded. The client makes a call to the specific API, to check for prize.

Inside the API logic, first I am checking how many available prize types are there and for this I am checking if `(awardedCount < totalCount)`. Here I am getting a list of prizes that i am passing to the chance algorithm and getting a specific type of prize in return. After this I am updating the table data for that specific type of prize by `awardedCount = awardedCount + 1`.

This is working perfectly till I am having multiple concurrent calls to the API. I have tested by making a hundred concurrent calls, and keeping `totalCount = 5`. And many times more prizes are being awarded than is intended, I have got 6 or 7 prizes being awarded on multiple tests with concurrent calls. I believe this is because of the multiple threads calling the API and the SQL queries being executed from there not synchronised accordingly, which is very natural in such a case.

Code is given below:

```
public function claimPrize($criteria) {
    // Check login
    if(AuthHelper::loginStatus($criteria)) {

        // Get available prizes
        $availablePrizes = $this->getPrizes();

        // Award a prize
        $awardedPrize = $this->selectPrize($availablePrizes);

        // Update awarded prize
        $response = $this->updatePrize($awardedPrize);
    }
}

private function getPrizes() {
    $prizesQuery = DoctrineQuery::from('cms_prizes')
                    ->select('*')
                    ->addWhere('awardedCount < totalCount');

    $prizesAvailable = $prizesQuery->execute();

    return $prizesAvailable->toArray();
}

private function selectPrize($availablePrizes) {
    // Chance calculation done here
    return ChanceHelper::getPrize($availablePrizes);
}

private function updatePrize($awardedPrize) {
    $prizesQuery = DoctrineQuery::from('cms_prizes')
                    ->select('*')
                    ->addWhere('type = ?', array($awardedPrize['type']))
                    ->getFirst();

    $prizeModel = $prizesQuery->execute();

    if($prizeModel) {
        $prizeModel->awardedCount = $prizeModel->awardedCount + 1;
        
        $prizeModel->save();
    }
    
    return $prizeModel;
}
```

I need some help on how to handle this issue. The API is written in PHP and I am using MySQL for database.

P.S.: The title might be vague as I could not come up with anything that will explain this problem in short. If so is the case, please help me out on that as well.

Comment: You must provide the code.

Comment: Perhaps a temporary [table lock](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-table-locking) will do the trick?

Comment: @Akina Yeah, sorry.. I have added it now.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Temporary table lock will only be effective for the same session no? This API will be called by different users at the same time. Could you please explain a bit more elaborately?

Comment: What happen in your code is that it first checks if `(awardedCount < totalCount)`, then executes some PHP code, and then does `awardedCount = awardedCount + 1`. While it executes some PHP another session may have asked `(awardedCount < totalCount)`. By locking, for reading, the `cms_prizes` table during the session of an user you can prevent this.

Comment: Another option is to do `(awardedCount < totalCount)` and `awardedCount = awardedCount + 1` in one query. But this can get ugly.

Comment: Yes, so table lock would work, but inside the session of a single user, when another user is calling the api at the same time, the lock will not be valid.

And for the other option, to combine the 2 queries, it will not be too viable in my case, because result from the SELECT statement will be used to generate the specific prize for which value needs to be incremented. So the queries cannot be combined.

Really stuck with this :(

Comment: Table locks are done on the database level, so it is valid for all PHP sessions. See: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-table-locking